# Simple for loop works incorrectly on some phones. Bad optimization?

Tags: java, android, for-loop

I have a problem with simple for loop and no idea what may be cause of the problem.

In short - instead of generating *1, 2, 3, 4, 5...* values, I receive *4, 4, 4, 4, 8...*

Situation:
In my application I need to generate an `int array[]` filled with values from 1 to N. It works fine in 99% of cases, however rarely I am receiving complaints from users, because numbers are generated incorrectly for them, breaking logic of the app. Thanks to app's version with special logging around the problematic code I was able to pinpoint location of the problem, but I have no idea what can be causing it. Here's the code:

```
// problematic code
(...)
int[] randomIds = new int[mColumns * mRows];
for (int i = 0; i < randomIds.length; i++) {
    randomIds[i] = i + 1;
}
int debugNoValues = 36;
logIntArrayValues(randomIds, debugNoValues);
(...)

// logging method, used to pinpoint the place  
// at which wrong values are first seen    
private void logIntArrayValues(int[] array, int n){
    String s = "";
    for(int i=0; i<array.length && i<n; i++){
        s+=array[i]+" ";
    }
    Logger.log(s);
}
```

Because of the strange nature of the problem, I have pasted actually used code, without changing anything.

Variables `mColumns` and `mRows` can take values between 3 and 6, and those values are always equal, resulting in sizes of 9, 16, 25 or 36.

Variable `debugNoValues` was added for tests only, to potentially limit number of logged values. In current state it doesn't limit anything.

Now the strangest part - values received by users reporting the problem (logged by `Logger.log(s);`), are as below:

`4 4 4 4 8 8 8 8 9 
 4 4 4 4 8 8 8 8 12 12 12 12 16 16 16 16 
 4 4 4 4 8 8 8 8 12 12 12 12 16 16 16 16 20 20 20 20 24 24 24 24 25 
 4 4 4 4 8 8 8 8 12 12 12 12 16 16 16 16 20 20 20 20 24 24 24 24 28 28 28 28 32 32 32 32 36 36 36 36`

I am unable to reproduce the problem on any of my test devices. Reports come from devices using Android 7.x and having MediaTek processors (at least when I received information about system and device).

Any ideas what could be causing such behavior? I am suspecting some kind of strange optimization of the loop, but I was unable to find any information about it. Besides that I am clueless.

Comment: You don't pass `randomIds` to another thread at any point and mess with it there?

Comment: Try using a lambda in Arrays to set your values.

public static <T> void setAll(T[] array,
                              IntFunction<? extends T> generator)

Comment: @Carcigenicate
No. You can see everything I do with it between initialization and the moment strange values are logged. After presented lines I only use it to shuffle those values and later copy to other array. Besides that it is never used again.

Comment: I wonder what would happen if you declared the variable `i` as an instance variable with the `volatile` keyword.

Comment: @Koger OK, just thought I'd ask. Call me a cynic, but from my experience here, people tend to omit the most important code relevant to a problem...   like the code that passes the data to a seperate thread.

Comment: @Carcigenicate no problem. I would suspect something like that myself

Comment: @CharlesSpencer interesting suggestion. I will try it out in next test version send to the user.

Comment: @Totoro, he wouldn't really be able to use fancy Java8 stuff, Android is stuck in land of Java6 or Java 7 for the majority part. There are clever tricks to bring some features of Java8 to Android, but not those don't work with methods.

Comment: @CharlesSpencer, I mean... normally, local variables don't need to be `volatilized` because no two threads can possibly see the same variable.

Comment: @Koger, for performance reasons, try to not append directly to `String` in your `log` method. Use `StringBuilder.append`. Not that it would solve the problem by itself though.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov Yeah, it shouldn't be necessary, but I was just trying to figure out a way to jog the JIT compiler to run this correctly, and I was hoping that this would force it to write out `i` to memory instead of using a register.  Hard to say exactly what the problem is, though.

Comment: @CharlesSpencer, it may indeed be the case of reimplementing an `Arrays.setAll(int[], IntUnaryOperator)` locally, because at that point array value should be seen as true function result based on index, ineligible for any sort of optimization along these lines.

Answer (score 0):

Its seems there is no problem with the above given code section , may be values are reinitialize in some other code segment.

Comment: Values are logged in the visible code section, further changes should not affect it